# Using vector graphics in iPhone games

Tags: iphone, ios, vector, vector-graphics

I'm Flash/AS3 developer and I'm wondering how some iPhone developers use vector assets in their games.

For example, "Lil' Pirates": this games looks like vector-based, it's zooming and unzooming easily, but I can't get any information about using vector assets at iOS.

Answer (score 7):

Quartz 2D is a pretty lightweight framework for vector based graphics.  It's very well documented...

[Quartz Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)

In particular I'd pay particular notice to layering and performance...

[Quartz Layering and Performance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_layers/dq_layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH219-TPXREF101)

If performance is a worry I'd also have a read through the core animation documentation.  Core animation uses CALayers to cache vectors drawn with Quartz to in-memory bitmaps.  These CALayers can then be transformed and translated through the animation APIs.  If you intend to perform a lot of drawing this is the route I would recommend.