# Vector art on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, pdf, svg

We've now got 4-resolutions to support and my app needs at least 6 full-screen background images to be pretty. Don't want to break the bank on megabytes of images.

I see guides online about loading PDFs as images and custom SVG libraries but no discussion of prectically.

Here's the question: considering rendering speed and file size, what is the bet way to use vector images in iOS? And in addition, are there any practical caching or other considerations one should make in real world app development?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5283103/716216

Comment: What kind of images are you working with? Particularly, are they like photographs, or more like graphics?

Comment: more like graphics, the original art is in SVG format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to consider for simple graphics, such as the type of thing used for backgrounds, etc., is just to render them at runtime using CG.

For example, in one of our apps, instead of including the typical repeating background tile image in all the required resolutions, we instead draw it once into a CGPatternRef, then convert it to a UIColor, at which point things become simple.

We still use graphic files for complex things, but for anything that's simple in nature, we just render it at runtime and cache the result, so we get resolution independence without gobs of image files.  It's also made maintenance quite a bit easier.

Comment: thats what i do. for backgrounds i use 1 tile of around 30x30 or 50x50 px that is tilable and make it a UIColorWithPattern